# How to rebuild a complex azure environment

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault, azure-resource-manager

I have a complex azure environment where there are so many components and dependencies.

Should I divide it to multiple deployments ? Even one resource has lots of dependencies.

Such as with the keys involving service fabric

[image]

Comment: two words - arm templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, as 4c74356b41 says, I suggest you could use arm template to achieve your requirement.

> Resource Manager template - A JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) file that defines one or more resources to deploy to a resource group. It also defines the dependencies between the deployed resources. The template can be used to deploy the resources consistently and repeatedly.

By using arm template. you could use [linked templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) to link different resources to achieve one resource has lots of dependencies.

More details about what is arm template and getting started, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#template-deployment).

Besides, there are also multiple arm template example, you could refer to this **[url](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates)** to know how to create the template.

Besides, if you have created a resource group and it contains multiple resources, you could directly download its deploy template for next deployment by using automation script feature.

Notice: Not all the resource will be automatic included in the auto template.

More details, you could refer to this image:

[image]

Comment: so using linked templates I would be able deploy step by step I guess.